# Group by similarity of string on a single table

Tags: string, oracle, grouping, matching

I need your help in writing a Oracle SQL query for below requirement.

Source data as below:

```
CLAIM_NUMBER       ADDRESS_1            ADDRESS_2
1001               220 CHIRAG ST         OHIO
1003               220  ST CHIRAG        OHIO
1004               19874 CURLEY AVE      ORLANDO
1005               10874  CURLEY AVE     ORLAND
1002               220 CHIRAG ST         OHIO
1006                579 MLK Dr           NASHVILLE
```

Requirement: if ADDRESS_1||ADDRESS_2>90% matches another record in the table then generate a group id (random unique id)

```
CLAIM_NUMBER       ADDRESS_1            ADDRESS_2     group_id
1001               220 CHIRAG ST         OHIO          134
1003               220  ST CHIRAG        OHIO          134
1004               19874 CURLEY AVE      ORLANDO       2985
1005               10874  CURLEY AVE     ORLAND        2985
1002               220 CHIRAG ST         OHIO          134
1006                579 MLK Dr           NASHVILLE     3098

WITH ACCT_GRP AS
(
SELECT NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_1)),'NA')||NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_2)),'NA') CONCAT ,
    CASE WHEN  
UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER(
NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_1)),'NA')||NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_2)),'NA')
LAG(
NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_1)),'NA')||NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_2)),'NA')
) OVER 
  ( ORDER BY
    NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_1)),'NA')||NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_2)),'NA')
   )
) *100<=90
THEN rownum
ELSE
null
END SIMILARITY_PCT
from src_table
),
ACCT_GRP_SUB AS
(
select concat,SIMILARITY_PCT from ACCT_GRP where SIMILARITY_PCT is not null
)
select 
ACCOUNT_ID,ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_1, ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_2,
SIMILARITY_PCT
from src_table stg left join ACCT_GRP_SUB grp
on 
case when 
UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER(
NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_1)),'NA')||NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_2)),'NA'),grp.concat
)*100>90 
then grp.concat else null end = grp.concat
order by NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_1)),'NA')||NVL(UPPER(TRIM(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_STR_2)),'NA');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common requirement, and unfortunately it is illogical - and therefore, of course, it can't be implemented. Here is the issue: suppose rows 1 and 2 are more than 90% similar (by WHATEVER definition). Suppose also that rows 2 and 3 are more than 90% similar. These two assumptions DO NOT IMPLY that rows 1 and 3 are more than 90% similar! Yet you must group rows 1 and 2 together, and also 2 and 3, so rows 1, 2, 3 must all be in the same group (even though 1 and 3 are not "sufficiently similar").

Now imagine that rows 5 and 6 are not sufficiently similar. Later we add row 7, which is more than 90% similar to row 5, and also more than 90% similar to row 6. Now what? Now you must group rows 5 and 6 together!

Made-up example:

```
row 1  ABCDEFGHIJ
row 2  ABCDEFGHIX
row 3  ABCDEFGHYX
```

All three strings are ten letters long. Row 1 and row 2 have 9 characters in common (in the same positions) so by one measure they are "90% similar". Same with rows 2 and 3; but rows 1 and 3 are only 80% similar.

Bottom line: the whole concept is fatally flawed - there's no clarification of the problem statement that will make it meaningful.

The mathematical (theoretical, academic) concept behind this discussion is that of "equivalence relation". A relation is an equivalence relation if it is reflexive (every element is in relation with itself), symmetric (if A and B are in the relation, then so are B and A) and **transitive** (if A and B are in that relation, and so are B and C, then A and C are in the relation). The concept you are working with is a relation that is reflexive and symmetric, but it is not TRANSITIVE - and therefore it is not an equivalence relation. On the other hand, dropping "things" into groups is logically the same thing as defining an **equivalence** relation. You can't create "groups" based on a relation that is not transitive.